# What does continuously payable annuity mean?

Tags: interest-rates, annualized, principal-components

I am preparing for F< exam but I am unable to understand the meaning of continuously payable annuity.

What does it mean?  An example would be great.

Comment: What do you think about this [explanation](http://www3.nd.edu/~cstanton/courses/math30610/lectures/lecture02-04-15.pdf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the context of bonds / fixed income an annuity is a payment which is made at regular time intervals - a cupon. A continuous one is simply being paid for an unlimited amount of time.

```
PV = Cupon/ (1+r)^1 + ...... Cupon/ (1+r)^t
```

just to add to Bob's comment above, a "continuously compounding" annuity is re-invested at the same rate every month on top of your principal value and previous annuity payments - gaining interest on interest. the formula is this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me to understand this.